# Unit testing dependency injections

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon, sinon-chai

I want to mock dependencies in a class but I cannot find the right way to achieve that. Using sinon for the unit testing. For example:

```js
const { classB } = require("./classes/classB");
const { classC } = require("./classes/classC");
const sinon = require("sinon");

class classA {
    constructor() {
        this.classB = new classB();
        this.classC = new classC();
    }
 
    doSomething() {
        const data = this.classB.getInfo();
        const processed = processInfo(data);
        this.classC.processedData(processed);
        
    }
    
    processInfo(data) {
        // doesSomeProcessing
    }
}

module.exports = {
    classA
};

describe("classA", () => {
    describe("when instantiated", () => {
        it("calls classB's getInfo once, classC's processedData data once.", () => {
            sinon.stub(classB);
            let clsA = new classA();
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(classB.getInfo);
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(classC.processedData);
            // Also can we do something like this?
            // when classB.getinfo.then(provideMockData) 
            // so that we can mock the calls being made to avoid actual calls?
        });
    });
});
```

I tried doing research around this but could not find a workable solution. Any insight will be super helpful! Thanks in advance and apologies for any trouble caused!

Comment: Don't instantiate b and c in the constructor, pass instances as arguments. Then just pass spies in your tests.

Comment: @JaredSmith So we don't have a way of direct testing for dependencies? Although this can work, I don't like the idea of passing instances as arguments for one reason: When my use-case expands, I end up passing these arguments to a lot of functions resulting in a code smell. Ref: https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list

Comment: Yes, having a long parameter list is definitely a good and sufficient reason to abandon dependency injection and write hard-to-test classes. Especially in a language that can easily handle partial application and ad hoc factory functions. Not to mention has destructuring for object arguments to simulate keyword parameters. You should totally write it the way you did </sarcasm>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stub out dependencies with [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/).

E.g.

`classA.js`:

```js
const { ClassB } = require('./classB');
const { ClassC } = require('./classC');

class ClassA {
  constructor() {
    this.classB = new ClassB();
    this.classC = new ClassC();
  }

  doSomething() {
    const data = this.classB.getInfo();
    this.classC.processedData(data);
  }
}

module.exports = { ClassA };
```

`classB.js`:

```js
class ClassB {
  getInfo() {
    return 'real data';
  }
}

module.exports = { ClassB };
```

`classC.js`:

```js
class ClassC {
  processedData(data) {
    return 'real process data';
  }
}

module.exports = { ClassC };
```

`classA.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('66751571', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const classBInstanceStub = {
      getInfo: sinon.stub().returns('teresa teng'),
    };
    const classCInstanceStub = {
      processedData: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const ClassBStub = sinon.stub().returns(classBInstanceStub);
    const ClassCStub = sinon.stub().returns(classCInstanceStub);
    const { ClassA } = proxyquire('./classA', {
      './classB': { ClassB: ClassBStub },
      './classC': { ClassC: ClassCStub },
    });
    const clsA = new ClassA();
    clsA.doSomething();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(classBInstanceStub.getInfo);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(classCInstanceStub.processedData, 'teresa teng');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  66751571
    ✓ should pass (2326ms)


  1 passing (2s)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   81.82 |      100 |      50 |   81.82 |                   
 classA.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 classB.js |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
 classC.js |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot @slideshowp2